# How do I make a class whose constructor looks like the constructor of a built-in class?

Tags: ruby, constructor

`Complex` is a built-in class. To make a `Complex` object, I write:

```
Complex(10, 5)
```

But if I create my own class `Thing`:

```
class Thing
  def initalize()
  end
end
```

to create a new `Thing`, I have to write:

```
Thing.new(...)
```

Is it possible to create a constructor for `Thing` so I can write:

```
Thing(...)
```

and have it act just like a built-in class such as `Complex(1,1)`?

Comment: Those aren't constructors of built-in classes, though... (That's a hint.) The source for these is available, btw.

Comment: To expand on Dave's point, those in capitals followed by parentheses are not classes, but are methods.

Comment: `Complex` and all the other "I'm really a function but Ruby doesn't have functions" methods are just methods in [`Kernel`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Complex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Dog
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet
    puts 'hello'
  end
end


def Dog(x)
  Dog.new(x)  #Create a new instance of the Dog class and return it.
end


d = Dog("Rover")
d.greet

--output:--
hello
```

Comment: Cool Thanks! Still getting used to Ruby, coming from Python I would think your example would just replace the Class Dog with a Function Dog - but of course it doesn't.

Comment: @quizdog, Yeah, ruby is a lot trickier.  There are no global methods in ruby; a def is always part of some class.   A def attaches itself to whatever class is the *current class*.   It so happens that the current class at the toplevel is Object.  So, a toplevel def is actually a (private) method in the Object class.  As a result, defining a def inside the Object class has no effect on the Dog class.

Comment: It's more that Ruby will give preferential treatment to constants (which it expects start with upper-case letters) that are actual constants; `Dog(x)` is only invoked as a method because Ruby knows it's looking for a method due to the passed arguments. If you defined a zero-argument method `Dog` and then tried to invoke it without parentheses, you'd get the class instead.

Comment: @ChrisHeald, I was trying to make the point that the Dog class is in a different scope than the Dog def, so the Dog def does not "replace" the Dog class.

Answer (score 6):

`Complex` can refer to either the [`Complex` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Complex.html), or to the [`Complex` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Complex) defined in Kernel:

```
Object.const_get(:Complex) #=> Complex
Object.method(:Complex)    #=> #<Method: Class(Kernel)#Complex>
```

The latter is called a global method (or global function). Ruby defines these methods in [`Kernel`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Kernel.html) as both, private instance methods:

```
Kernel.private_instance_methods.grep /^[A-Z]/
#=> [:Integer, :Float, :String, :Array, :Hash, :Rational, :Complex]
```

and singleton methods:

```
Kernel.singleton_methods.grep /^[A-Z]/
#=> [:Integer, :Float, :String, :Array, :Hash, :Rational, :Complex]
```

Just like any other method in Kernel:

> These methods are called without a receiver and thus can be called in functional form

You can use [`module_function`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.1/Module.html#method-i-module_function) to add your own global method to `Kernel`:

```
class Thing
end

module Kernel
  module_function

  def Thing
    Thing.new
  end
end

Thing          #=> Thing                      <- Thing class
Thing()        #=> #<Thing:0x007f8af4a96ec0>  <- Kernel#Thing
Kernel.Thing() #=> #<Thing:0x007fc111238280>  <- Kernel::Thing
```

Comment: The Object class includes the Kernel module, try `p Object.private_instance_methods.grep /^[A-Z]/`, so your example ends up creating a private instance method in the Object class, which is the exact same thing a toplevel def does and with less typing.

Comment: @7stud yes, the difference is subtle, but the OP wanted to know how methods like the built-in ones can be created. And Ruby defines them in `Kernel`, not in `Object`.

Comment: Would the down-voter leave a comment, please? Is my explanation wrong or misleading?