# How can ruby `Complex` be called like a method when it is a class?

Tags: ruby

Ruby core library Complex class can be called as if it is method.

```
Complex.class #=> Class
Complex(1, 2) #=> (1+2i)
```

How is this possible?

I could override `[]` but not `()`.

```
class MyComplex
  def self.[](real, image) # This works.
    "#{real} + #{image}i"
  end
  def self.()(real, image) # This is not allowed in ruby.
    "#{real} + #{image}i"
  end
end

MyComplex[1,2] #=> "1+2i"
MyComplex(1,2) # I want this working like Complex class.
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28845222/477037

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, then you need to put the initialization inside the `Kernel` module.

```
module Kernel
  def MyComplex
   MyComplex.new
  end
end
```

Ruby core lib defined [`#Complex()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Complex) inside the `Kernel` model. If you define it inside the `Kernel` module, then you can take the advantage of those methods using *mixin* like below :

```
class MyComplex
  def initialize( real, image )
    "#{real} + #{image}i"
  end
end

module Kernel
  def MyComplex( real, image )
    MyComplex.new real, image
  end
end

class Klass < BasicObject
  include ::Kernel

  def create_object a, b
    MyComplex(a, b)
  end
end

p Klass.new.create_object 1, 2
# >> #<MyComplex:0xa01b008>
```

If you define it in *top level*, that method becomes a *private method of class `Object`*, then you have no simple way to reuse the method :

```
def MyComplex( real, image )
  MyComplex.new real, image
end

class Klass < BasicObject
  def create_object a, b
    MyComplex(a, b)
  end
end

p Klass.new.create_object 1, 2
# `create_object': undefined method `MyComplex'
```

Comment: But Ruby's Complex is class, not method. I wanna know how Complex can behave like method when it is class.

Comment: @JecholLee: The parser spots the different use of the constant `Complex` (as either a class or method reference), and the language allows this dual use.

Comment: “then you need to put the initialize inside the `Kernel` module” — what? This is nonsense. Please see @NeilSlater ’s answer, it’s correct.

Comment: @cremno Just let me know.. why not liking to put it inside the `Kernal`, rather in `Object` ? I am really not finding out the _non sense_ comment that had been put to me.. Although that comment was very _rude_.

Comment: Ruby defines global functions within `Kernel` (not `Object`) as both, private instance methods and module functions. You can use [`module_function`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Module.html#method-i-module_function) to achieve the same in plain Ruby. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28850096/477037 for an example.

Comment: @mudasobwa The answer you marked as _correct_, is not giving you the object of the `MyComplex` class, rather a _string_ object. So, what is your plan to call methods of `MyCustom` class using `String` instances... ?

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is wrong. `Complex` in `Complex.class` is a class, and `Complex` in `Complex(1, 2)` is a method defined on `Kernel`. They are different things.

Comment: But, Complex seems to be defined at Object. `Kernel.constants.include? :Complex # false`, `Object.constants.include? :Complex # true`.

Comment: I don't get the relevance of your code in the comment. Your code checks for constants, not methods. `method(:Complex).owner #=> Kernel`.

Comment: I was confused. Thanks. And I learned #owner now. Thanks for it also!

Comment: @JecholLee furthermore, `Object` includes `Kernel`, so these methods become available in all objects.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually surprisingly simple,and AFAIK this is how Ruby and Ruby libraries do it:

```
class MyComplex
  def self.[](real, image) # This works.
    "#{real} + #{image}i"
  end
end

def MyComplex( real, image )
  "#{real} + #{image}i"
end

MyComplex[1,2] # "1+2i"
MyComplex(1,2) # "1+2i"
```

Comment: @mudasobwa Why are you forcing OP? Are you sure, there will not be any answer from anyone ?

Comment: @Neil Slater I appreciated your answer, but I just needed more time so others can answer too.

Comment: @JecholLee: No problem, that is how SO works best, if you have time to assess all answers. I don't think my answer is *complete* in any case.